# Compile-On-Save with Typescript 0.9

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, visual-studio-extensions

So I know that the Typescript 0.9 Alpha is out, and one of the drawbacks is the ability to Compile-On-Save is not available yet.

**My question is, is there another way to get this feature?**

Web Essentials has a compile-on-save feature with Typescript 0.8.1, does that work for 0.9? Is there another extension available that can provide this feature?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and the Typescript extension. I am working in Typescript projects (if that makes any difference).

Thanks in advance!

Griffork.

Comment: If all else fails you could always use WebStorm. It has a file watcher that is independent of your Typescript version: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWXGMug_Rmo

Comment: Thanks :) Although that was technically an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install web essentials and Typescript 0.9.0-alpha. Compile on save works fine. At least it does on my machine.

Comment: I just tested this and it works (+1) - you don't even need to install 0.8.x first - you can just install Web Essentials against 0.9 and it compiles fine.

Comment: It's worth noting at this point for people looking at this thread that Compile On Save is supported natively in the Typescript plugin in the latest (0.9) release.

Comment: It is also worth noting that Web Essentials have just removed all TypeScript features - these should be natively supported within Visual Studio soon.

Comment: Should be, but isn't yet :(