# Typescript "Compile on Save" is not working on VS 2015 Update 3

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

The "Compile on save" feature isn't working for me in my Visual Studio 2015 with update 3.I am start working on Angular2 project with MVC5.Thats why I need to re compile or when change in .ts file is detect and show updated output on my browser.

my tsconfig.json file have below code:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
},
"compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
 ]
}
```

I have Typescript 2.4.1.0 tools for Visual Studio 2015 installed. Image Ref:

[image]

or in my PC I have Typescript 2.4.1 is installed.  Image Ref:
[image]

I also tried to add entry in path variable. As Ref in this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750964/typescript-compile-on-save-feature-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015) and Image:
[image]

I checked my typescript version is updated or out dated but I found this:

[image]

This is my .csproc file code:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>true</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>true</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I also check Image Ref:

[image]

Last one which I try and got error is on the below link from which I follow
[Mikaël Mayer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711542/typescript-compile-on-save-with-visual-studio-2013):

Here is my error which I got while building:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. The working directory "F:\Projects\ecommerce\ecommerce\js" does not exist.    ecommerce   F:\Projects\ecommerce\ecommerce\ecommerce.csproj    352

Image:
[image]

Below is the other references on which I tried but nothing is working for me:

[Ref#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494475/compile-on-save-with-typescript-0-9)

[Ref#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430126/typescript-compile-on-save-not-working-in-cordova-jsproject-2015)

[Ref#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992794/compile-on-save-is-not-working-for-asp-net-5-apps-in-vs-2015-rc)

[Ref#4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704077/typescript-disable-compile-on-save-in-vs-2015-ctp-6)

[Ref#5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559653/vs2015-typescript-compile-to-single-file-on-save-not-working)

[Ref#6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711542/typescript-compile-on-save-with-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score -1):

I've experienced a similar problem in the past and I resolved it by changing the project property:

```
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
```

This can be found on the *Typescript Build* tab of the project properties:

[image: Compile on save]

Hope this gets you going.  Good luck!

Comment: I have `tsconfig.json` in my project folder so thats why above project properties is disable for me.

Comment: Ah.  And I apologize.  I missed that you had already done this above.  (I somehow missed your snippet from the .csproj)

Comment: Maybe take a step back and try each thing individually first. Run your build in VSCode or from the command line to make sure that saving on compile works there. If so, then remove the tsconfig and see if just using the Visual Studio MSBuild tasks (csproj and project properties tab) will work. I've have seen a lot of instance where--despite stated support--attempting to use a tsconfig inside of Visual Studio 2015 has had issues/conflicts.